# Not Found page when waitress start

Tags: python, flask, waitress

I get this error when I access the default page after starting the flask server using the waitress.

The code is:

```
from app import app
from waitress import serves

if __name__ == '__main__':
     serves (app, host = "0.0.0.0", port = 8080)
```

I access the page `http://localhost:8080` in the browser

erro:
[Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wmc5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a url handler:

```
@app.route('/') 
def index():
    return "hello"
```

Comment: I have a controller file to do this, will it be a problem when accessing it? When it was like app.run () it worked perfectly

Comment: So, does your `localhost` map to `0.0.0.0`?  Try: `serves (app, host = "127.0.0.1", port = 8080)`

Comment: I figure out the problem, I accidentally deleted the call to the controller.

Follow the line I had deleted:
`from app.controllers import default`

I have a controller folder and inside it there is a default.py file with code similar to yours. Thanks, your comment helped me